# Does anyone know how to get the time to format correctly when the Hour/Minute/Second is a SINGLE digit in python or pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, formatting

Some rows in my dataframe have time as "13:2:7" and I want them to be "13:02:07".

I have tried applying pd.to_datetime to the column but it doesnt work

Can someone please suggest some method to format the time in standard format

Comment: You can try `strftime`. Apply if before printing to datetime columns. It will produce strings of any desired format from datetime objects.

Comment: Yes thanks for mentioning. strftime can also be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

I solved it through pandas `to_timedelta`

`pd.to_timedelta("13:2:3")` or pass the column of dataframe through it

result:

"13:02:03"

ps: you will get result as "0 days 13:02:03"

In order to remove 0 days

```
df["column_name"].astype(str).map(lambda x: x[7:]))
```

We will slice of the initial 0 days string present

Note: The final result will be in form string

In case you want time object ,

Use pandas `pd.to_datetime` or `strftime` from `datetime` module

Comment: With this code you'll get unexpected result with time when hours start with 0 (like 07:15:15). It'll strip that leading zero too. `lstrip` argument is used like set of characters, so while any of them is present at the left end of string - it'll be stripped.

Comment: Yes I realized that, thanks for pointing out.I have used slicing operation to remove the days part